# javascript or jquery keyboard event

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to control the next and previous buttons also by clicking the keybord left and right buttons (37 and 39).

i tried by writing a javascript code to do it but it worked only for the first and second tab.

here is the full code without css

```
<?php 

      $nexticon = '<span style="font-size: 28px;"><i class="fi-arrow-right"></i></span>';
      $previousicon = '<span style="font-size: 28px;"><i class="fi-arrow-left"></i></span>';

     ?>


<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 7;">


     <!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" autocomplete="off">


<!-- fieldsets -->
<fieldset>


 bla bla bla page 1


     <button class="next action-button-next" type="button" style=" position: absolute; top: 990px; left:380px; background-color: Transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat; border: none; cursor:pointer; overflow: hidden; outline:none; "> <?php echo $nexticon ?></i></button>


     </fieldset>

<fieldset>







    <form name="change">


 bla bla bla page 2

     <button class="previous action-button-previous" type="button" style=" position: absolute; top: 990px; left:135px; background-color: Transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat; border: none; cursor:pointer; overflow: hidden; outline:none; "> <?php echo $previousicon ?></button>
     <button class="next action-button-next" type="button" style=" position: absolute; top: 990px; left:380px; background-color: Transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat; border: none; cursor:pointer; overflow: hidden; outline:none; "> <?php echo $nexticon ?></button>
</fieldset>


<fieldset>


   bla bla bla page 3


     <button class="previous action-button-previous" type="button" style=" position: absolute; top: 990px; left:135px; background-color: Transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat; border: none; cursor:pointer; overflow: hidden; outline:none; "> <?php echo $previousicon ?></button>
     <button class="next action-button-next" type="button" style=" position: absolute; top: 990px; left:380px; background-color: Transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat; border: none; cursor:pointer; overflow: hidden; outline:none; "> <?php echo $nexticon ?></i></button>
</fieldset>


<fieldset>


    bla bla bla page 4


     <button class="previous action-button-previous" type="button" style=" position: absolute; top: 990px; left:135px; background-color: Transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat; border: none; cursor:pointer; overflow: hidden; outline:none; "> <?php echo $previousicon ?></button>
     <button class="next action-button-next" type="button" style=" position: absolute; top: 990px; left:380px; background-color: Transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat; border: none; cursor:pointer; overflow: hidden; outline:none; "> <?php echo $nexticon ?></i></button>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>


   bla bla bla page 5

     <button class="previous action-button-previous" type="button" style=" position: absolute; top: 990px; left:135px; background-color: Transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat; border: none; cursor:pointer; overflow: hidden; outline:none; "> <?php echo $previousicon ?></button>
     <button class="next action-button-next" type="button" style=" position: absolute; top: 990px; left:380px; background-color: Transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat; border: none; cursor:pointer; overflow: hidden; outline:none; "> <?php echo $nexticon ?></i></button>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>


    bla bla bla page 6

     <button class="previous action-button-previous" type="button" style=" position: absolute; top: 990px; left:135px; background-color: Transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat; border: none; cursor:pointer; overflow: hidden; outline:none; "> <?php echo $previousicon ?></button>
     <button class="next action-button-next" type="button" style=" position: absolute; top: 990px; left:380px; background-color: Transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat; border: none; cursor:pointer; overflow: hidden; outline:none; "> <?php echo $nexticon ?></i></button>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>


   bla bla bla page 7


     <button class="previous action-button-previous" type="button" style=" position: absolute; top: 990px; left:135px; background-color: Transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat; border: none; cursor:pointer; overflow: hidden; outline:none; "> <?php echo $previousicon ?></button>

</fieldset>
     <!-- progressbar -->
<ul id="progressbar">
<li class="active">1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
</ul>
     </form>







<!-- jQuery easing plugin -->    
        <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script>
        $(function() {

        //jQuery time
        var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
        var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
        var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

        $(".next").click(function(){
                if(animating) return false;
                animating = true;

                current_fs = $(this).parent();
                next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

                //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
                $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

                //show the next fieldset
                next_fs.show(); 
                //hide the current fieldset with style
                current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
                        step: function(now, mx) {
                                //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                                //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
                                scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
                                //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
                                left = (now * 50)+"%";
                                //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
                                opacity = 1 - now;
                                current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
                                next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
                        }, 
                        duration: 800, 
                        complete: function(){
                                current_fs.hide();
                                animating = false;
                        }, 
                        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
                        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
                });
        });

        $(".previous").click(function(){
                if(animating) return false;
                animating = true;

                current_fs = $(this).parent();
                previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

                //de-activate current step on progressbar
                $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

                //show the previous fieldset
                previous_fs.show(); 
                //hide the current fieldset with style
                current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
                        step: function(now, mx) {
                                //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                                //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
                                scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
                                //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
                                left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
                                //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
                                opacity = 1 - now;
                                current_fs.css({'left': left});
                                previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
                        }, 
                        duration: 800, 
                        complete: function(){
                                current_fs.hide();
                                animating = false;
                        }, 
                        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
                        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
                });
        });



        });
        </script>
```

Comment: I don't see any key event handlers in the code shown. Also, what if the focus is in a text input? (Assuming you have text inputs...) Then the arrow keys should move the cursor within the input, not perform page navigation.

Comment: @nnnnnn
i added new answer with the full code the code works perfect but i want also to controle the next and previous from keyboard arrows

Comment: Please don't add additional details in an answer, [edit] your question and add it there.

Comment: i edited the post

Answer (score 0):

Where do you place your handlers? I can't guess your perferred approach.

This is what would I do:
Since binding with individual instance may force the user focusing those fieldset containers, I would register a global event handler with the document. By checking the visibility of the current visible fieldset and its child nav buttons, it is able to perform corresponding action of showing your animation.

```
$(function() {
  $('#ctnFieldSets div').each(function( index ) {
    var fs = $(this);

    // hide buttons
    if (!fs.prev('div').length) fs.find('button.prev').hide();
    if (!fs.next('div').length) fs.find('button.next').hide();

    // hide pages
    if (index > 0) fs.hide();
  });

  // register handlers for buttons
  $('#ctnFieldSets div button.prev, #ctnFieldSets div button.next').bind({
    click: function(e) {
      var btn = $(this);
      var fs = $(btn.parent('div')[0]);

      fs.hide();
      if (btn.is('.prev')) {
        // animation here //
        $(fs.prev('div')[0]).show();
        return;
      }

      if (btn.is('.next')) {
        // animation here //
        $(fs.next('div')[0]).show();
        return;
      }
    }
  });

  // register global event handler for keydown. you may bind to other objects if
  // you don't want to be global event handler

  $(document).bind({
    keydown: function(e) {
      // you should check targets here. skips when target could input text
      if ($(e.target).is('input,textarea')) return;

      var fs = null;

      switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
          fs = $($('#ctnFieldSets div:visible').first()[0]);
          if (!fs.find('button.prev:visible').length) return;

          // animation here //
          fs.hide();
          $(fs.prev('div')[0]).show();
          break;

        case 39:
          fs = $($('#ctnFieldSets div:visible').first()[0]);
          if (!fs.find('button.next:visible').length) return;

          // animation here //
          fs.hide();
          $(fs.next('div')[0]).show();
          break;

        default:
          return;
      }
    }
  });
});


<div id="ctnFieldSets">
  <div><button class='prev'>Prev</button>Div1<input><button class='next'>Next</button></div>
  <div><button class='prev'>Prev</button>Div2<input><button class='next'>Next</button></div>
  <div><button class='prev'>Prev</button>Div3<input><button class='next'>Next</button></div>
</div>
```